# How can one customize Django Rest Framework serializers output?

Tags: python, django, json, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model that is like this:

```
class WindowsMacAddress(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField(unique=True)
    mapping = models.ForeignKey('imaging.WindowsMapping', related_name='macAddresses')
```

And two serializers, defined as:

```
class WindowsFlatMacAddressSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    address = serializers.Field()

class WindowsCompleteMappingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.Field()
    macAddresses = WindowsFlatMacAddressSerializer(many=True)
    clientId = serializers.Field()
```

When accessing the serializer over a view, I get the following output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "macAddresses": [
            {
                "address": "aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"
            }, 
            {
                "address": "bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb"
            }
        ], 
        "clientId": null
    }
]
```

Almost good, except that I'd prefer to have:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "macAddresses": [
            "aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa",
            "bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb"
        ],
        "clientId": null
    }
]
```

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a [custom serializer field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) and implement `to_native` so that it returns the list you want.

If you use the [`source="*"` technique](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments) then something like this might work:

```
class CustomField(Field):
    def to_native(self, obj):
        return obj.macAddresses.all()
```

I hope that helps.

**Update** for djangorestframework>=3.9.1

According to [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields), now you need override either one or both of the `to_representation()` and `to_internal_value()` methods. Example

```
class CustomField(Field):
    def to_representation(self, value)
        return {'id': value.id, 'name': value.name}
```

Comment: All the links given are broken, could you please update it

Answer (score 7):

Carlton's answer will work do the job just fine.  There's also a couple of other approaches you could take.

You can also use `SlugRelatedField`, which represents the relationship, using a given field on the target.

So for example...

```
class WindowsCompleteMappingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.Field()
    macAddresses = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='address', many=True, read_only=True)
    clientId = serializers.Field()
```

Alternatively, if the `__str__` of the `WindowsMacAddress` simply displays the address, then you could simply use `RelatedField`, which is a basic read-only field that will give you a simple string representation of the relationship target.

```
# models.py
class WindowsMacAddress(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField(unique=True)
    mapping = models.ForeignKey('imaging.WindowsMapping', related_name='macAddresses')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

# serializers.py
class WindowsCompleteMappingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.Field()
    macAddresses = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)
    clientId = serializers.Field()
```

Take a look through the [documentation on serializer fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) to get a better idea of the various ways you can represent relationships in your API.

Comment: Hmm I thought `RelatedField` and `SlugRelatedField` only work with `ModelSerializer`?

Comment: All the relational fields work with Django model relationships.  They'll work just fine either used on a `Serializer` or a `ModelSerializer` class.