# Django Rest Framework make OnetoOne relation ship feel like it is one model

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have my `User` saved in two different models, `UserProfile` and `User`. Now from API perspective, nobody really cares that these two are different.

So here I have:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
```

and

```
class UserPSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    full_name = Field(source='full_name')
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('url', 'mobile', 'user','favourite_locations')
```

So in `UserPSerializer` the field `user` is just a link to that resource. But form a User perspective there is really no reason for him to know about `User` at all.

Is there some tricks with which I can just mash them together and present them to the user as one model or do I have to do this manually somehow.

Comment: Check out the [answers to this related question][1]. I think it covers what you need. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012665/how-can-one-customize-django-rest-framework-serializers-output/

Comment: This answer is also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19806796/2789332

Comment: Remember to accept if you like an answer below!

Answer (score 34):

You can POST and PUT with [@kahlo's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23444426/647002) if you also override the create and update methods on your serializer.

Given a profile model like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar_url = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)  # e.g.
```

Here's a user serializer that both reads and writes the additional profile field(s):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # A field from the user's profile:
    avatar_url = serializers.URLField(source='profile.avatar_url', allow_blank=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'avatar_url')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile', None)
        user = super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        self.update_or_create_profile(user, profile_data)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile', None)
        self.update_or_create_profile(instance, profile_data)
        return super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

    def update_or_create_profile(self, user, profile_data):
        # This always creates a Profile if the User is missing one;
        # change the logic here if that's not right for your app
        Profile.objects.update_or_create(user=user, defaults=profile_data)
```

The resulting API presents a flat user resource, as desired:

```
GET /users/5/
{
    "url": "http://localhost:9090/users/5/", 
    "username": "test", 
    "avatar_url": "http://example.com/avatar.jpg"
}
```

and you can include the profile's `avatar_url` field in both POST and PUT requests. (And DELETE on the user resource will also delete its Profile model, though that's just Django's normal delete cascade.)

The logic here will *always* create a Profile model for the User if it's missing (on any update). With users and profiles, that's probably what you want. For other relationships it may not be, and you'll need to change the update-or-create logic. (Which is why DRF [doesn't automatically write through a nested relationship](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.6.3/rest_framework/serializers.py#L765-L774) for you.)

Answer (score 12):

I just came across this; I have yet to find a good solution particularly for writing back to my `User` and `UserProfile` models. I am currently flattening my serializers manually using the `SerializerMethodField`, which is hugely irritating, but it works:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    mobile = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_mobile')
    favourite_locations = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_favourite_locations')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'mobile', 'favourite_locations')

    def get_mobile(self, obj):
        return obj.get_profile().mobile

    def get_favourite_locations(self, obj):
        return obj.get_profile().favourite_locations
```

This is horribly manual, but you do end up with:

```
{
    "url": "http://example.com/api/users/1",
    "username": "jondoe",
    "first_name": "Jon",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "email": "jdoe@example.com",
    "mobile": "701-680-3095",
    "favourite_locations": [
        "Paris",
        "London",
        "Tokyo"
    ]
}
```

Which, I guess is what you're looking for.

Comment: I think a SerializerMethodField is read-only, so this wouldn't allow creating or modifying the profile fields through the user resource. You can also get read-only with a *little* less typing using the suggestion in @kahlo's answer. (E.g., `mobile = serializers.CharField(source='profile.mobile', read_only=True)`).

Comment: `mobile = serializers.SerializerMethodField()` will use function `get_mobile` by default and will throw an error for redundancy if you specify the field manually.

Answer (score 6):

I would implement the modifications on the `UserPSerializer` as the fields are not going to grow:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class UserPSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.CharField(source='user.url')
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name')
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.last_name')
    email = serializers.CharField(source='user.email')

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('mobile', 'favourite_locations',
                  'url', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
```

Comment: this is a clean solution for GETting the users, but does not work for POSTing a new user.