# DjangoRestFramework - How to access other fields of a OneToOneField reverse relationship using a model serializer?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using the default User model and am also extending it with a UserExtended model:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    countryName = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    countryCode = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

class UserExtended(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="userextended")
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

I am trying to follow what is documented here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations

This is my UserSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(UserSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # call the super() 
            for field in self.fields: # iterate over the serializer fields
                self.fields[field].error_messages['required'] = 'Enter a valid %s.'%field # set the custom error message

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'userextended')

        extra_kwargs = {
                    'password': {
                        'write_only': True,
                    }
                }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            email = validated_data['email'],
            username = validated_data['username'],
            password = validated_data['password'],
        )
        return user
```

My issue is, if the end user does not fill out the "Country" section of the form before submitting it, Django sends an error message to the front end saying "Enter a valid userextended". "userextended" is the name of the reverse relationship, and every user object is linked to a userextended object and vise-versa. "userextended" is mandatory, but the end user does not have to specify a "userextended" field when creating a user object because that is already a given (the moment the end user creates a user object, the user object will have a reverse relationship with a UserExtended object by default).

The end user has to fill out a "Country" section in the form because Country is what is required from the end user. With that said, how do I get Django to say "Enter a valid Country" rather than "Enter a valid userextended"?

If the end user successfully saves a user object, and submits "Canada" in the "Country" section in the form, how does DRF know to save "Canada" as the country? Because currently, it looks like DRF thinks the "Country" section in the form refers to the "userextended" reverse relationship field.

What I'd expect is, in the "fields" array for the user serializer, I use dot notation? Something like this?:

```
fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'userextended.country')
```

Edit: I just created a UserExtended serializer as well, like so:

```
class UserExtendedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserExtended
        fields = ('country')
```

but I don't know how to "merge" this serializer with the original UserSerializer.

Comment: Have you tried to create a Serializer for UserExtended add it to your UserSerializer?

Comment: @ejey Yes, I just tried doing what IgorPomaranskiy suggested below (see the answers section). I commented on his response and mentioned why the solution doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution given by Igor works only when you want to fetch the details of users because of read_only field. Serializer doesn't support nested write by default. To write a nested object you should override the create method of UserSerializer.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(UserSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # call the super()
            for field in self.fields: # iterate over the serializer fields
                self.fields[field].error_messages['required'] = 'Enter a valid %s.'%field # set the custom error message

    country = serializers.RelatedField(source='userextended.country')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'country')

        extra_kwargs = {
                    'password': {
                        'write_only': True,
                    }
                }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            email = validated_data['email'],
            username = validated_data['username'],
            password = validated_data['password'],
        )
        country=Country.objects.get(pk=validated_data['country'])
        UserExtended.objects.create(user=user, country=country)

        return user
```

Data to send when creating:

```
{'username':'sachin', 'email': 'email@gmail.com', 'password': 'abc', 'country':2}
```

Comment: Thanks. If you view the answer by KevinStone on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772457/django-rest-framework-creating-custom-user he mentions to implement a custom restore_object() method as well. I did research, and realized restore_object() has been replaced in DRF 3 with create() and update(): http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#serializers In your answer, you defined create, but what is the correct way of defining update() in this scenario?

Comment: Also, when I try the code you posted above, I get an AssesrtionError saying "relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, or set read_only=`True`." and it refers to the line "country = serializers.RelatedField(source='userextended.country')". How come I am getting this error? When I add "queryset=UserExtended.objects.all()" then I get an error saying "RelatedField.to_internal_value() must be implemented.". Any idea why these two errors are coming up?

Comment: Syntax of update function is this  def update(self, instance, validated_data): which you can see rest_framework/serializers.py in ModelSerializer class. For country , can set read_only=True then no error will come, but as you have overrided create function country will be updated.

Comment: One More thing, i would recommend you to use custom user model instead of onetoone relationship. I used this method and you will fall into such problems every now and then.
You can read up on this article https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/08/07/migrating-custom-user-model-django/ and also django documentation

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Lastly, you used "country = serializers.RelatedField(source='userextended.country')". Should it be PrimaryKeyRelatedField instead (because in the example of data to send, you sent an integer for the 'country' field - which I'm assuming is a primary key)? Over here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield It mentions that "PrimaryKeyRelatedField may be used to represent the target of the relationship using its primary key." So how come you chose to use "RelatedField" rather than "PrimaryKeyRelatedField"?

Comment: In addition to my comment above, over here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer it mentions that "Any relationships such as foreign keys on the model will be mapped to PrimaryKeyRelatedField." And it gives an example of making a reverse relationship using a "PrimaryKeyRelatedField" (which is why I'm wondering if "RelatedField" or "PrimaryKeyRelatedField" is correct). And on a side note, where is the documentation for RelatedField anyways? I tried searching for it here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/ and I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the next:

1. Write serializer for UserExtended model instances.
2. Use this serializer to serialize `userextended` field.

Something like this:

```
class UserExtendedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
# define serializer here...

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'userextended')

    userextended = UserExtendedSerializer(read_only=True)
```

Comment: When I do this, the end user does not need to fill out the "Country" section of the form, and Django does not send a "Please enter a valid userextended" message to the front end either. It seems as if this solution makes the userextended / Country field not mandatory for the end user when creating a UserSerializer object.

Comment: ```Please enter a valid userextended``` is anyway useless message. If you have a form, error messages should be related to exact fields or whole  form (for example, when there are issues with DB access).

Comment: If you have to save extended userprofile in this serializer, try ```userextended = UserExtendedSerializer()``` (without ```read_only=True```).

Comment: Right,"Please enter a valid userextended" is useless, which is my issue. Django doesnt see that "country" is the required field, it thinks that userextended (the OneToOneField relationship) is what is required by the end user. How do I make it so that the "country" field is what is required? If I do read_only=True then Django allows users to submit the form without filling in the "userextended" field. If I do read_only=False then Django again sends an error message saying "Please enter a valid userextended" because Django doesnt know that the country field is what is required.

Comment: Did you make ```UserExtendedSerializer```? Did you make serializer for ```Country```? Is ```country``` required in ```UserExtendedSerializer``` and/or in model?

Comment: yup, I updated my post to show my UserExtendedSerializer: class UserExtendedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): class Meta: model = UserExtended fields = ('country') Country is required in both UserExtendedSerializer and the UserExtended model. Have a look at SachinGupta's answer.. Would you agree with the way he did it?