# Django Rest Framework - accessing nested json object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm providing JSON to a view like so -

```
{
    "username": "name",
    "first_name": "john",
    "last_name": "doe",
    "email": "jdoe@hotmail.com",
    "profile": {
        "company": "abc corp"
    }
}
```

I'm then passing it into the following view to post -

```
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        uuid = generate_uuid(request.data.get('username'))
        data = {'username': request.data.get('username'),
                'first_name': request.data.get('first_name'),
                'last_name': request.data.get('last_name'),
                'email': request.data.get('email'),
                'company': request.data.get('profile').('company'),
                'uuid': str(uuid)}
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print serializer.data
#            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I'm having difficulty in understanding how to structure the `data` to maintain the nested value as you can see I'm also including a field for a `uuid` which will also be in the nested `profile` object.

These are then being passed into my serializer here -

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'profile')
```

My view currently as it is gives a syntax error on this line -

```
'company': request.data.get('profile').('company'),
```

I know it's wrong just not sure how it should be structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct version of this line:

```
'company': request.data.get('profile', dict()).get('company'),
```

What this does is supply an empty dict as a default argument if the data is missing a 'profile' object, or if it has one, call get('company') on that.

Comment: hmmm... I don't think I put my question right.  I see what this is doing but looks to be flattening the json.  I found that just doing `'profile': request.data.get('profile')` puts in the nested company automatically but then how to I include the `'uuid'` in the nested `'profile'`?

Comment: @whoisearth What exactly is `uuid`? Your UserSerializer does not have a `uuid` field and I'm pretty sure the default Django User model also does not. Where exactly is `uuid` getting saved?

Comment: I'm generating a uuid and storing it in UserProfile model which I'm then linking to User using a OneToOneField.

Comment: I marked this as correct but I ultimately ended up using the documentation here - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772457/django-rest-framework-creating-custom-user`