# rest serializer for nested class

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

i am very new to django , and started writing serializers and come with this issue

i have extended my user class from user_profile class

now i want to write the user_profile serializer to save data in user Profile and user

this is  my user serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email','password','is_staff')
```

it working fine

this is my user_profile class

```
class User_Profile(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_profile'
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

now i write this serializer for user profile

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(source='user.email')
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    class Meta:
        model = User_Profile
        fields = ('url', 'phoneNumber','email','username')
```

but it does save the user and user profile data , and it gives error like this

```
Cannot assign "{u'username': u'test12', u'email': u'test@12.cm'}": "User_Profile.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

Please help!

Comment: Refer this , this is exactly what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517438/django-rest-framework-make-onetoone-relation-ship-feel-like-it-is-one-model/23444426#23444426

Comment: Show what you're doing to save your `UserProfile` instance.