# Missing field in a Django User custom model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

After experimenting with classical serializers in Django REST, I am currently trying to work with custom models i.e. my model has a `OneToOneField` field.

My model (in `models.py`) is a custom `User`:

```
class Friend2(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    add_field = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

And I serialize it (in `serializers.py`) with (based on [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517438/django-rest-framework-make-onetoone-relation-ship-feel-like-it-is-one-model)):

```
class Friend2Serializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    add_field = serializers.CharField(source='friend2.add_field')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'add_field')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('friend2', None)
        user = super(Friend2Serializer, self).create(validated_data)
        self.create_or_update_user(user, profile_data)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('friend2', None)
        self.create_or_update_profile(instance, profile_data)
        return super(Friend2Serializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

    def create_or_update_user(self, user, profile_data):
        profile, created = Friend2.objects.get_or_create(user=user, defaults=profile_data)
        if not created and profile_data is not None:
            super(Friend2Serializer, self).update(profile, profile_data)
```

To POST data to register a new user, I use the following code snippet:

```
import requests
import json

json_data = {'username': 'mylogin12', 'password': 'mypassword', 'email': 'mymail12@wanadoo.fr', 'add_field' : 'myaddfield'}
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/register_new_user', json=json_data)
```

And in my `views.py`:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def register_new_user(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('POST request !')

        print(request.data)
        serializer = Friend2Serializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():

            serializer.save()
            print('save friend!')
            return HttpResponse(status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        else:
            print(serializer.errors)
            return HttpResponse(status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

So far, it works.

However, when I try to retrieve all the registered users with:

```
def get_all_users(request):

    all_friends = Friend2.objects.all()

    serial = Friend2Serializer(all_friends, many=True)
    json_data = JSONRenderer().render(serial.data)

    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

I get the following error:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `username` on serializer `Friend2Serializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Friend2` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Friend2' object has no attribute 'username'.
```

But I do not understand why the `username` field does not exist has it is an attribute of the `User` model.

**EDIT:**:

I have tried to modify my serializer based on :

```
class Friend2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
password = serializers.CharField(source='user.password')
email = serializers.CharField(source='user.email')
add_field = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True)

class Meta:
    model = Friend2
    fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'add_field')
    depth = 1

def create(self, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('friend2', None)
    user = super(Friend2Serializer, self).create(validated_data)
    self.create_or_update_user(user, profile_data)
    return user

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('friend2', None)
    self.create_or_update_profile(instance, profile_data)
    return super(Friend2Serializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

def create_or_update_user(self, user, profile_data):
    profile, created = Friend2.objects.get_or_create(user=user, defaults=profile_data)
    if not created and profile_data is not None:
        super(Friend2Serializer, self).update(profile, profile_data)
```

But now, I get the following error:

```
raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
```

TypeError: 'user' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: It seems you are passing an object `Friend2` to your serializer which cannot interpret correct since your `Friend2` model does not have the attributes your `User` model has such as `username`. I know what I said seems pretty obvious. I'm trying to think in a way to fix that...

Comment: `Friend2Serializer` expects a `queryset` which should contain all the fields, but it only has `user`, and `add_field`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Friend2` model has a `user` field, not `username`. Replace `username` with `user` in your serializer class.

Comment: I totally agree with you that my Friend2 model has only user and add_field as attributes. However, as mentionned in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517438/django-rest-framework-make-onetoone-relation-ship-feel-like-it-is-one-model, Django should be able to "guess" that the username attributes is an attribute of my User model, no?