# DRF Serializers for Models with OneToOne relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Given Django Models that have a OneToOne relationship, how does one setup the Django Rest Framework Serializers & Views so that to the API consumer the end-point for paying in cash and paying in cheque include the payment model and allow for all CRUD functionality?

I've tried following [this SO Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18517438/1082673) but I can't seem to replicate the functionality.

**Models**

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    """
    Payment Log
    """
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_merchant")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_customer")
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(PaymentMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    trx_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)

class PaymentCash(models.Model):
    """
    Cash payments
    """
    payment = models.OneToOneField(Payment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    date_paid = models.DateField()
    # Other fields

class PaymentCheque(models.Model):
    """
    Cheque deposits
    """
    payment = models.OneToOneField(Payment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    cheque_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # Other fields
```

**Sample View**

```
class PaymentCashViewSet(ListCreateRetrieveUpdateViewSet):
    """
    Cash payment view
    """
    queryset = PaymentCash.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PaymentCashSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, HasPermission)
```

**Current Serializer**
This though does not make use of all the fields in the Payment Model.

```
class PaymentCashSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serialize model"""
    class Meta:
        model = PaymentCash
        fields = ('payment', 'date_paid')
```

*Using: Django==1.10.2 & djangorestframework==3.5.1*

Comment: Could you show the corresponding serializers?

Comment: Added a serializer for Cash Payment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your models and views, I happen to have wrote some serializers for your view. May be it would n't be of much help for you, as I have limited information about your project as much.

But, on my knowledge so far, I happen to write the serializers for you like this,

```
class EntitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = '__all__'

class PaymentMethodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PaymentMethod
        fields = '__all__'

class PaymentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = EntitySerializer()
    merchant = EntitySerializer()
    payment_method = PaymentMethodSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Payment
        fields = ('id', 'payment_method', 'trx_amount', 'customer', 'merchant')

class PaymentCashSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serialize model"""
    payment = PaymentSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = PaymentCash
        fields = ('payment', 'date_paid')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        payment_data = validated_data.pop('payment')
        customer_data = payment_data.pop('customer')
        merchant_data = payment_data.pop('merchant')
        payment_method_data = payment_data.pop('payment_method')
        customer, c = Entity.objects.get_or_create(**customer_data)
        merchant, m = Entity.objects.get_or_create(**merchant_data)
        payment_method, p = PaymentMethod.objects.get_or_create(**payment_method_data)
        payment = Payment.objects.create(customer=customer, merchant=merchant, payment_method=payment_method, **payment_data)
        instance  = PaymentCash.objects.create(payment=payment, **validated_data)
        return instance

    def update(self, validated_data):
        payment_data = validated_data.pop('payment')
        customer_data = payment_data.pop('customer')
        merchant_data = payment_data.pop('merchant')
        payment_method_data = payment_data.pop('payment_method')
        customer, c = Entity.objects.get(**customer_data)
        merchant, m = Entity.objects.get(**merchant_data)
        payment_method, p = PaymentMethod.objects.get(**payment_method_data)
        payment = Payment.objects.get(customer=customer, merchant=merchant, payment_method=payment_method, **payment_data)
        instance  = PaymentCash.objects.get(id=validated_data.get('id'))
        instance.payment = payment
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

The custom create and update method, would require some modifications from you as I have only wrote for an ideal scenario. Hope this would be much help to you.

Comment: Thanks. Shows what is required and got me unstuck

Comment: Can you explain what this objects.get(**data) is returning? if the fields are updated then will it update them and return the updated object? Thank you.

Comment: `**data` is destructuring syntax for python objects, it creates an object on the fly with all the keys & values from `data`. Mostly used as syntactic sugar and for readability. You can look it up as object destructuring in python.